# MySQL : When stored procedure parameter name is the same as table column name [continue]

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, backticks

Let's say a have a stored procedure SetCustomerName which has an input parameter Name, and I have a table customers with column Name. So inside my stored procedure I want to set customer's name. If I write

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = Name;
```

this is incorrect and I have to write (for example)

```
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = Name;
```

So, there is a link about backticks (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) but it's not explained deep enough how to use them (how to use them with parameters and column names).

And there is a very strange thing (at least for me): You can use backticks either way:

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = `Name`;
//or
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = Name;
//or even
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = `Name`;
```

and they all work absolutely the same way.

Don't you think this is strange? Is this strange behavior explained somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you need to escape using backticks in the first place.
In a statement *UPDATE x SET a = b*, *a* must always refer to a column of *x*. *b* however can either be a variable or a column. Given how [local scope and variable resolution works in stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/local-variable-scope.html), *b* will always refer to the local variable, even if a column with the same name in *x* exists.

Thus, I am unable to reproduce your problem. I tried this way:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM comments;
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | parent_id | content |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         0 | bar     | 
|  2 |         0 | baz     | 
+----+-----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE foo(IN content TEXT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   UPDATE comments SET content = content;
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> CALL foo('changed!');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT * FROM comments;
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | parent_id | content  |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 |         0 | changed! | 
|  2 |         0 | changed! | 
+----+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, the comment-table's column *content* gets updated, even though *content* is also the name of the parameter of the stored procedure *foo*.

Are you sure that UPDATE customers SET Name = Name; gives you an error?
With the above explanation, it seems logical that

```
UPDATE customers SET Name = `Name`;
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = Name;
UPDATE customers SET `Name` = `Name`;
```

all have the same effect.

**Edit:** The situation would be different for SELECT statements, of course.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce the problem with UPDATE and INSERT anymore either :) I don't know why..
What about WHERE clause? What I want to write something like this: ... WHERE Name = Name